# Once and for all: Which FEM plattform should I use for a very large multiphysics simulation?

Tags: finite-element, linear-solver, mesh, multiphysics

I'm fooling around with the decision on how to build a multiphysics simulation for too long now (also several questions in this forum). First, I thought it would be possible/necessary to write most of it from scratch and by combining various libraries. (I did this in Matlab and Python to get familiar with the model, so I basically have an idea how to do it.) Now I learned more about more integrated platforms, for example Trilinos and PETSc. Then I learn about MOOSE that pretty much claims to be the jack of all trades. And probably a dozen other platforms.

For me as an unexperienced PhD student, it seems to be almost impossible to do an educated decision about which platform to use. So I really, really need the help of the community.

Requirements:

- Multiphysics and nonlinear equations
- Various regions with different physics and internal boundaries to each other
- Very large simulations on many computing nodes
- In these days it's probably mandatory to leverage GPUs.
- Geometry will be generated programmatically and it would be very convenient to have an integrated mesher that can generate meshes from parametrically defined geometries (signed distance functions for example).
- Can be integrated into own software
- Liberal license, like BSD or (L)GPL

**If you started such a project right now, what FEM platform would you count on?**

Comment: Or you can write your own code on top of PETSc. The most complex part of an FE code is parallel assembly & solve, and PETSc takes care of both.

Comment: Deal.II (https://www.dealii.org/), if compiled with appropriate 3rd-party libraries (PETSc, etc), would probably do what you're interested in. The library does seem to restrict you to quad/hex elements, so you'll have to determine if that meets your requirements. The owner of the library is active on this site and can likely be more specific about each of your requirements, as I have only used it for very basic things.

Comment: Perhaps not a useful answer, but I would not start such a project! Your first four requirements are quite challenging, especially for an 'unexperienced PhD student'. Perhaps you can think of ways to simplify the problem, for example by decoupling the physics, time scales and spatial scales?

Comment: @JannisTeunissen: As I said in my post, I already wrote most of the simulation from scratch for a single processor to get familiar with the model and with FEM. So I feel in the position to do it, but the enormous number of existing libraries and frameworks makes a choice extremely difficult.

Comment: @Michael : The fact that you are comfortable with your simulation in a single processor does not mean that the implementation in parallel will be easy. Migrating your program from sequential to parallel can be very cumbersome, especially in you haven't thought about parallel implementation before writing your code in sequential. Sometimes you need to re-write your code from scratch just to prepare parallel communication between processors. The is even more complicated if your intention is to code in GPU without knowing about the basic in parallel communication.

Comment: @Coriolis With PETSc your parallel code will look more or less your serial code (see the examples). Mine own unstructured code is written just a few hundred lines and scales rather well up to 4K cores. Actually, I can more or less guarantee that your parallel PETSc code will be smaller than your serial, non-PETSc code.

Comment: @Coriolis: As far as I see, all of the mentioned libraries provide abstraction layers for vectors and matrices so that you do not see much of a difference whether it's on one or on many cores. But in the end it's exactly the point of my question: Which platform helps me most to avoid the cumbersomeity of parallel computing?

Comment: @Stali : Interesting, I should take a look at PETSc. I'm bit skeptical however about your speed-up for 4K cores, you may not need a such amount of cores to improve your CPU time without being overwhelmed by MPI communications, causing a drop in performance.

Comment: @Michael : Actually it depends of the complexity of your simulation. If by parallel computing you mean parallel decomposition, load balancing and just a simple exchange of vectors between processes, this kind of library will suit your needs.

Comment: @Coriolis You really should give it a try.

Comment: I don't think that this is a wise idea. Why not pick an existing FEM like deal.ii or Fenics? Although there are more options out there like Code-Aster or Elmer. To write what you want from scratch right and then do the pertinent verifications with Manufactured Solutions will take a lot of time.